# The right method to install Appx bundle application using Powershell via SCCM

Tags: installation, powershell, windows-store-app

Is the below method of installing and uninstalling .Appx packages correct when installing through SCCM as a Device collection.

Install:

```
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -PackagePath "Packagepath.appxbundle" -DependencyPackagePath $Dep.FullName -SkipLicense -Online
```

Uninstall:

```
$name = "App_name"
    $PackageName  = Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq $name}
    $PackageName.PackageName
    Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -PackageName $PackageName.PackageName -AllUsers -Online
```

Comment: I could be assuming here, but, this question would lead one to believe you are new to System Center specifically and Powershell beginner. System Center is of course very large and serious enterprise product. It is not something to learn on the job as you can cause major damage to the environment. It's best to get serious hands-on training from an SCCM trainer before messing wiith it. As well as spend the needed time learning PowerShell and App deployment whether you use SCCM ot not. [There are PowerShell toolkits for app deployments as well](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PSDeploy/).

Answer (score 0):

SCCM notwithstanding.

PowerShell is Powershell no matter where you use it from.

The cmdlets (properties, methods, etc...) do not change and you use the cmdlets as documented in the PowerShell help files.

There are plenty of docs from Microsoft and other blogs on using SCCM to install applications (appx, msi, etc...) in the SCCM docs and all over the web and [videos on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=sccm%20deploy%20appx).

> ['sccm install appx'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=sccm%20install%20appx&form=ANNTH1&refig=9ce367cd4858432e99b4baa260cc8efe&sp=-1&pq=sccm%20install%20appx&sc=8-17&qs=n&sk=&cvid=9ce367cd4858432e99b4baa260cc8efe)
>
> [Deploy applications with Configuration Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/apps/deploy-use/deploy-applications)
>
> [Create Windows applications in Configuration Manage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/apps/get-started/creating-windows-applications)r
>
> [Deploy an Application from Windows Store for Business via System
>   Center Configuration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teju_shyamsundar/2016/05/30/deploy-an-application-from-windows-store-for-business-via-system-center-configuration-manager/)
>
> [Step by Step Video Guide to Create Deploy APPX Apps via SCCM and Troubleshooting Tips](https://www.anoopcnair.com/sccm-app-deployment-process-appx)

SCCM uses tasks to process code, but that does change how PowerShell works.

Comment: *Generally* yes, but it is worth noting that a lot of stuff in SCCM (including custom scripts in most cases) run as the SYSTEM account, which does affect how certain commandlets like `Add-AppxPackage` work, so just because a script works in the ISE under your account doesn't mean it will work in SCCM. `psexec -i -s powershell.exe` is a good way to test.